# Linked authentication Integrating with Symfony2 (FOSUserBundle)

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, linkedin-api, fosuserbundle

I am developing an application using symfony2.2.

I'm trying to authenticate my users via **Linkedin** *Or* **FOSUserbundle** on symfony2.

I can authenticate users on linkedin by [`happyr library`](https://github.com/HappyR/LinkedIn-API-client). It has also documentation for integrating it with symfony2, but its not complete.. i think that i should write custom user provider to login the user automatically after getting his info from linked, and my question is **HOW**?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could consider to use https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle

Offers adapter to many 3rdy party, including Linkedin, and is well documented.

This blog post offer an example of integration

http://m2mdas.github.io/blog/2013/11/21/integrate-hwioauthbundle-with-fosuserbundle/

Comment: I tried that.. but during installation composer says that it's not compatible with `kriswallsmith/Buzz` and then terminates the installation..

Comment: Don't think this should be a huge problem, but depends on your setup. Are you actually using  kriswallsmith/Buzz ?

Comment: I don't know what this bundle do!! i thought that it's part of symfony's base bundles..

Comment: It's part of the bundle. You tried version 0.3 right ? https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/tree/0.3

Comment: Maybe related to minimum stability of composer?

Comment: it's `"minimum-stability": "dev",`

Comment: Looks like you have  bundles with conflicting dependencies. Try looking at your composer.json. I cannot help further on this. Cheers!